# Refer to variable that refers to Application

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I am trying to put the value of a cell in a Msgbox that is in the left column (column A). This value needs to be picked though, depending on which value in column B is the lowest and it should be reused, with varying length of the rows (sometimes it is 200 rows sometimes 230 etc.)

So far I wrote:

```
Sub Flow()
'Check lowest value

Dim lowestValue As String


lowestValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets("ImportData").Range("B3:B290"))

MsgBox "Lowest Flow" & vbNewLine & _
(lowestValue) & vbNewLine & _
"at " & (lowestValue.Offset(0, -1))

End Sub
```

Obviously `lowestValue.Offset(0, -1))` does not work, but basically that is what I would like to achieve: find the lowestValue and then look one column to the left and also display that value in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Sub Flow()
'Check lowest value
    Dim rData                 As Range
    Dim lowestMatch
    Set rData = Sheets("ImportData").Range("B3:B290")
    lowestMatch = Application.Match(Application.Min(rData), rData, 0)
    If Not IsError(lowestMatch) Then
        MsgBox "Lowest Flow" & vbNewLine & _
               rData.Cells(lowestMatch).Value & vbNewLine & _
               "at " & rData.Cells(lowestMatch).Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I have realized only now though that sometimes there is two or more times the same value in column B and I would need to get all the values from column A at these points. Column A has time stamps, so they are unique. Is there a way to tell in the message box lowest value of this at time X, time Y, time Z...?